# csrf verification in android getting Typeerror

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working an app in which i need csrftoken verification. I am receiving the cookie in each request and return again it in each request. The request in which i need csrf verification is below. I am sending the csrf in header and cookie also using localcontext. but i am getting Typeerror. the detail error given below. same as when I am sending only the csrftoken in header and no cookie with request its getting 403forbidden csrf verification failed. please help me tfo solve the issue.....

```
public JSONArray getLinkFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> param) throws IOException {

    // Making HTTP request
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "url: "+url);
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "csrfToken: " + PrefManager.csrfToken);
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Domain: " + PrefManager.domain);
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
       // httpPost.setHeader("Referer", url);
        httpPost.setHeader("X-CSRFToken", PrefManager.csrfToken);
        final BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        for (Cookie cookie: PrefManager.cookies) {
            cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "cookie: " + cookie.toString());
        }
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the Type error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
       <title>TypeError at /m/payment</title>
       <style type="text/css">
         html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
         body * { padding:10px 20px; }    </style>

       <script type="text/javascript">
       //<!--
         function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
             // Written by Jonathan Snook, http://www.snook.ca/jon; Add-ons by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
             var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && document.all)? document.all :
             oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
             var arrReturnElements = new Array();
             strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\-");
             var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + strClassName + "(\s|$)");
             var oElement;
             for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++){
                 oElement = arrElements[i];
                 if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)){
                     arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
                 }
             }
             return (arrReturnElements)
```

Values: [user_id=8, trxn_type=FP, subtrxn_type=N, schemes=[{"scheme_code":2390,"amount":5000}], session_key=0j467lrxgi8o1yhdcgnduc4czmoiyses]

cookie: [version: 0][name: csrftoken][value: O1xARAJ0ISMPeHId56Bk2boYW0XoKvwJ][domain: ......][path: null][expiry: null]

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution for that by sending Cookies same as i am receiving from the server end in each request. First store the cookie list you received from server and again send it to server.
`if(cookielist!=null) {
                for (Cookie cookie : cookielist) {
                    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            List <Cookie> cookies =  cookieStore.getCookies();
            cookielist=cookies;`